# Issues with connecting to OPENVPN

Tags: ubuntu, debian, vpn, openvpn

I am trying to configure Mullvad on openVPN - Debian

I have followed their online tutorial -

```
Install OpenVPN and resolvconf (sudo apt-get install openvpn resolvconf)
Extract the configuration files into /etc/openvpn/
Start with sudo /etc/init.d/openvpn start
```

And when trying to start, I get the error -

[FAIL] Starting virtual private network daemon: mullvad_linux failed!

I have no idea why it is doing this and I have spent hours trying to fix it.

Your help would be appreciated greatly

Comment: Read your syslog.  The OpenVPN daemon, and scripts give lots of useful information.  Possibly adjust your config to verb 4 for even more detail.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error when trying this on my Raspberry Pi 2. First I found that starting the OpenVPN with this command returns some useful information.

sudo /usr/sbin/openvpn --config /etc/openvpn/mullvad_linux.conf

This made it clear I needed to update the config file with the correct path for the other ca.cert, mullvad.crt, mullvad.key, crl.pem by prefixing them with /etc/openvpn

Next I ran into a error with invalid ciphers which prompted me to upgrade to the latest version of OpenVPN. I found a nice guide here (replacing the version number with 2.3.6).

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=89216&p=637279

Then I had an error related to IPv6 so I enabled that by editing /etc/modules using this guys instructions.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=15886

That left me with OpenVPN that initialized and then I got some weird timeouts but switching the config to connect to Sweden seemed to fix that!

Answer (score 0):

What specifically did you do for step 2 - extract the configuration files? Usually you need to tell openvpn what configuration file to use, unless there is only one conf file. You need something that looks like openvpn.conf and a certificate to go along with it, usually something.pem ... On RHEL, you'd put it in  /etc/openvpn/ ... Also, I'm not sure when it asks you for the credentials ... you may need to edit the conf file to point to a passwords file or the like if you want to run it as a daemon / service.

I'd try running openvpn on the CLI and pass it the configuration file...
 `sudo openvpn openvpn.conf`  and replace openvpn.conf with the actual conf file path...